# No RowCommand-event for GridView with extra rows added dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, webforms

So i have a GridView-control. That is set to a datasource, with paging of 20.

Though, in the RowDataBound-handler I add an extra row for each bound row, making it a total of 40 rows. These are supposed to be detailsrows, for the rows being databound. There is no problem adding these rows, and the grid is displayed as it should. However, buttons in rows on the lower half (the last 10 databound rows, 22, 24, etc) of the grid does not trigger RowCommand. All I get is an empty postback, reloading the page. Im suspecting that the gridview only triggers events for 20 (in this case, due to paging) rows, since the problem starts with 11th row (which is really the 22nd due to extra inserted rows).

If my assumption is correct, is there a way to work around this? Or will i have to rework my solution for showing row-details?

Comment: What happens if you use another event, for example `DataBound` or `PreRender`? See here for all available events: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events.aspx)

Comment: I sort of solved it by having all buttons making a postback with javascript using Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference, and settings the proper argument. And then checking for it in Page_Load. It works but makes the code way harder to follow...